# Why "Allowed Memory Size Exhausted" error turns out when using bigger size database

Tags: laravel-5, memory, eloquent

I had using eloquent relationship in my query (controller).

```php
$items = Item::with('section','category')
    ->where('item.statusid', '=', 1)
    ->get();
```

I had tested in my local and development server and success. But when I use the production database to the same code, it turns error:

> **Allowed Memory Size Exhausted**

I had tried changing php memory limit and disable query log, but failed. What else can I do to fix this?

**Update:**
The current production db with 'item' table consists of 1178 rows.

Comment: as the error message says, possibly the query result is too large for php to dealt with. you might want to increase the memory limit or, paginate your query to limit how many item you retrieve at a single time.

Comment: the memory limit already set as unlimited (-1) and also tried with 526M, 1048M. And for paginate..I am using datatable to display it, if I paginate the query, searchind datatable will be limited to the pagination list..not searching all results.

Comment: DataTable can do server side pagination as shown in their [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) and there is a [DataTable wrapper for laravel](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables). That being said, you can double check if you hit your machine's memory and if the limit is correctly set to `-1` as you have explained using [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).